# Retrieve Parent Model Through Pivot Table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently struggling with retrieving data towards a parent model. I'll drop my database, classes, and things I've tried before.

I have 4 tables: `sales_orders`, `products`, `work_orders`, and `product_sales_order` (pivot table between `sales_orders` and `products`).

##### `SalesOrder.php`

```php
class SalesOrder extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
            ->using(ProductSalesOrder::class)
            ->withPivot(['qty', 'price']);
    }
}
```

##### `ProductSalesOrder.php`

```php
class ProductSalesOrder extends Pivot
{
    public function work_orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(WorkOrder::class);
    }

    public function getSubTotalAttribute()
    {
        return $this->qty* $this->price;
    }
}
```

##### `WorkOrder.php`

```php
class WorkOrder extends Model
{
    public function product_sales_order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductSalesOrder::class);
    }

    public function sales_order()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            ProductSalesOrder::class, 
            SalesOrder::class
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Screen capture of my Database Workbench]

So, what I want to retrieve sales order data from work order since both tables don't have direct relationship and have to go through pivot table and that is product sales order. I've tried `hasOneThrough` and `hasManyThrough` but it cast an error unknown column. I understand that error and not possible to use that eloquent function.

Is it possible to retrieve that sales order data using eloquent function from `WorkOrder.php` ?

[image: Screen capture of Error Unknown Column]

Comment: I never used pivot in laravel. but I check it in Laravel Doc. as per documentation, we can define pivot like this... "->withPivot('active', 'created_by');" but you defined pivot in array like this.. ->withPivot(['kuantitas', 'harga', 'status_order']);  So try it by like this... ->withPivot('kuantitas', 'harga', 'status_order');  ... i hope this helps to you

Comment: @HarshPatel thank you for trying to help !!! In this case it is exactly the same, you can pass an `array` or multiple `parameters`, it will automatically convert to `array`. The problem here is the relation. `withPivot` does add information when retreving it from the pivot table so you can do something like `$model->pivot->harga` or `$model->pivot->kuantitas`, if you don't use `withPivot` then that will never work and throw an error.

Comment: @HarshPatel thank's for that information but as @matiaslauriti said it automatically convert to `array`

Comment: "So, what I want to retrieve sales order data from work order since both tables don't have direct relationship". If you need sales data from work order that means the tables ARE related, which begs the question: Why they don't have a relationship?

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata They have relationship but indirect and I don't need to save sales_order_id inside `work_orders` table since I can access it through `product_sales_order`

Comment: @KevinJonathan But what's the actual relation between sales orders and work orders? Can a work order exists without a sales order? Are work orders also related to products? I'm just trying to understand the logic of the database here.

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata `WorkOrder` can't exist without `SalesOrder` and `Product`. When I create work order, I need to know which product that need to be produce and which sales order that come from. And that's why I create one to many relationship between `ProductSalesOrder` to `WorkOrder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want using [`hasOneThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) as it goes from a table that has no ID related to the intermediate model.

In your example you are doing "the inverse" of [`hasOneThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through), as you are going from a model that has the ID of the intermediate model in itself, and the intermediate model has the ID of your final model. The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) shows clearly that [`hasOneThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) is used exactly for the inverse.

So you still should be able to fix this, and use a normal relation as you have the `sales_orders_id` in your model `SuratPerintahKerja`, so you can use a normal relation like `belongsTo` to get just one `SalesOrder` and define it like this:

```php
public function salesOrder()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SalesOrder::class, 'sale_orders_id');
}
```

If you want to get many `SalesOrder`s (if that makes sense for your logic), then you should just run a simple query like:

```php
public function salesOrders()
{
    return $this->query()
        ->where('sale_orders_id', $this->sale_orders_id)
        ->get();
}
```

Have in mind that:

1. I have renamed your method from `sales_order` to `salesOrder` (follow camel case as that is the Laravel standard...).
2. I have renamed your method from `sales_order` to `salesOrders` for the second code as it will return more than `1`, hence a `collection`, but the first one just works with one model at a time.
3. I see you use `sale_orders_id`, but it should be `sales_order_id`, have that in mind, because any relation will try to use `sales_order_id` instead of `sale_orders_id`, again, stick to the standards... (this is why the first code needs more parameters instead of just the model).
4. All pivot tables would still need to have `id` as primary and auto incremental, instead of having the `id` of each related model as primary... Because in `SuratPerintahKerja` you want to reference the pivot table `ProdukSalesOrder` but it has to use both `produks_id` (should have been `produk_id` singular) and `sale_orders_id` (should have been `sales_order_id`). So if you were able to use something like `produk_sales_order_id`, you could be able to have better references for relations.
5. You can see that I am using `$this->query()`, I am just doing this to **only** return a new query and not use anything it has as filters on itself. I you still want to use current filters (like `where` and stuff), remove `->query()` and directly use the first `where`. If you also want to add `->where('produks_id', $this->produks_id)` that is valid and doesn't matter the order. But if you do so, I am not sure if you would get just one result, so `->get()` makes no sense, it should be `->first()` and also the method's name should be `salesOrder`.
6. Sorry for this `6` tip/step, but super personal recommendation, always write code in **English** and do not write both languages at the same time like `produks` and `sales orders`, stick to one language, preferrably English as everyone will understand it out of the box. I had to translate some things so I can understand what is the purpose of each table.

If you have any questions or some of my code does not work, please tell me in the comments of this answer so I can help you work it out.

---

Edit:

After you have followed my steps and changed everything to English and modified the database, this is my new code:

First, edit `ProductSalesOrder` and add this method:

```php
public function sales_order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SalesOrder::class);
}
```

This will allow us to use relations of relations.

Then, have `WorkOrder` as my code:

```php
public function sales_order()
{
    return $this->query()->with('product_sales_order.sales_order')->first();
}
```

`first` should get you a `ProductSalesOrder`, but then you can access `->sales_order` and that will be a model.

Remember that if any of this does not work, change all the names to `camelCase` instead of `kebab_case`.

Comment: Apparently, there are some inconsistent within my database, I'll update it again. So actually that database that I designed quite different with the one that I implemented rn. And for languages I already consider it before, but ended up with using 2 languages. I'll try to translate it before posting it to any forum, thanks. @matiaslauriti

Comment: @KevinJonathan no worries, we are here to learn. Try my code and tell me if it works, or if you are going to change your DB so this code is outdated, what are you going to do ?

Comment: I already updated new DB up there, actually not that really different tho and I'll try ur suggestion and let u know the result

Comment: I tried to implement ur code, but it doesn't work since `work_orders` table doesn't have sales_order_id (I already update my Database Workbench in my post). So I tried the following code `$salesorder = SalesOrder::where($this->produk_sales_order()->sales_order_id)->get();` but ended up with another error

Comment: @KevinJonathan I have updated my answer, see if that works now.

Comment: I've followed through ur code, and it `does work`. But I want to know if I declare relationship inside `ProductSalesOrder` using `belongsTo` towards `SalesOrder` it won't disturb or give another errors right? Since `ProductSalesOrder` is a pivot class between `Product` and `SalesOrder`

Comment: @KevinJonathan it will not give errors, as it is a relation. It is true it is a pivot table, but it is a model, it doesn't matter if it is a pivot or not, it is still a model, and that is the only way of declaring relations. Also, a pivot table (in this case) will always return only one model, either `Product` or `SalesOrder` (but you have to declare the `Product` relation if you needed it, else don't worry about creating it). So, if this worked, could you mark my answer as correct, please ?

Comment: yup, I need to declare it again for `Product`. Anw thanks for ur help

Comment: @KevinJonathan no worries, remember to code only relations you need, if you don't use pivot product's relation, don't code it, there is no need.